# How can i capitalize first letter of Each Word in javascript, reactjs

Tags: javascript

I want to capitalize every first letter of Each Word in reactjs

Only Letter of Word capitalize but I want to capitalize every first letter of Each Word

```
const handleCapitalClick = () => {
    console.log("Capitalize first Word " + text);
    var firstChar = text.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    var restOfWords = text.slice(1, text.length);
    const Newtext = firstChar + restOfWords;
    setText(Newtext);

    // .split(' ') 
};
```

And I know `.split(' ')` I use for words.

Comment: See CSS: text-transform: capitalize

Comment: text[0].toUpperCase()+text.slice(1)